# Grouping results from stored procedure as JSON - Azure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Stored proc returning data in roughly this format

```
ID | Field1 | Field2 | Group  | Description
------------------------------------------------
1  |   A    |   A    |   g1   |  g1A description
1  |   A    |   A    |   g2   |  g2A description
2  |   B    |   B    |   g1   |  g1B description
2  |   B    |   B    |   g2   |  g2B description
3  |   C    |   C    |   g1   |  g1C description
3  |   C    |   C    |   g2   |  g2C description


SELECT
  a.ID,
  a.Field1,
  b.Field2,
  c.Group,
  c.Description
FROM A as a
  INNER JOIN B b ...
  INNER JOIN C c ...
```

In code, I am converting the dataset to JSON

```
[
  {
    ID: 1,
    Field1: A,
    Field2: A,
    Groups: {
      g1: g1A description,
      g2: g2A description,
    }
  }, {
    ID: 2,
    Field1: B,
    Field2: B,
    Groups: {
      g1: g1B description,
      g2: g2B description,
    }
  }, {
    ID: 1,
    Field1: C,
    Field2: C,
    Groups: {
      g1: g1C description,
      g2: g2C description,
    }
  }
]
```

I don't like that the procedure is returning mostly duplicate data in each row. Is there some way I can perform the grouping in SQL, so that the returned dataset is something like

```
ID | Field1 | Field2 | Groups  
------------------------------------------------
1  |   A    |   A    | 'Groups: { g1: g1A description, g2: g2A description }'
2  |   B    |   B    | 'Groups: { g1: g1B description, g2: g2B description }'
3  |   C    |   C    | 'Groups: { g1: g1C description, g2: g2C description }'
```

OR

```
 ID | Field1 | Field2 |        g1       |        g2
----------------------------------------------------------
 1  |   A    |   A    | g1A description | g2A description
 2  |   B    |   B    | g1B description | g2B description
 3  |   C    |   C    | g1C description | g2C description
```

---

Using the answer from 'D-Shih, I came up with this:

```
   SELECT
       a.ID,
       a.Field1,
       b.Field2,
       (
         SELECT 
           MAX(CASE WHEN [Group] = 'g1' THEN Description END) g1, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN [Group] = 'g2' THEN Description END) g2
         FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
       ) as Groups
   FROM A as a
      INNER JOIN B b ...
      INNER JOIN C c ...


    ID | Field1 | Field2 | Groups  
   ------------------------------------------------
    1  |   A    |   A    | '{ "g1": "g1A description", "g2": "g2A description" }'
    2  |   B    |   B    | '{ "g1": "g1B description", "g2": "g2B description" }'
    3  |   C    |   C    | '{ "g1": "g1C description", "g2": "g2C description" }'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4bf8a009fe91bbbd0f3246723a1f9eb4

Comment: You can't use the results of a stored procedure in a query. If you want to do so, you'll need to convert it to a function. If you want to generate *JSON* though, why not write a *different* query that uses [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? In SQL Server 2016 and later you could just add `FOR JSON AUTO` to get a JSON string with the results nested per table or `FOR JSON PATH` to specify the nesting through column names

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using Azure SQL so I do have access to the JSON functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second expect result can use condition aggregate function to make it.

```
SELECT ID,
      Field1,
      Field2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN [Group] = 'g1' THEN Description END) g1, 
      MAX(CASE WHEN [Group] = 'g2' THEN Description END) g2
FROM T
GROUP BY ID,Field1,Field2
```

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa60e60c43e612d31d3e90a3334e3e7b)

**NOTE**

`T` is your currently result set.